# Need help setting up RoboSpock

Tags: android, testing, groovy, robospock

I want to use RoboSpock for Testing my android apps, but I am stuck setting up my project. I created an example project which I have added to github.
https://github.com/DerSchimi/RoboSpockExample
This project contains a folder called AppLibrary which is an android-library. The App itself is inside the folder App.
All RoboSpock Tests should go inside the folder AppTests. I have configured everything, but when I try to run my tests I get this error message:

> WARNING: no system properties value for ro.build.date.utc
>
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: AppActivity for class: de.derschimi.app.MainActivitySpecification
> at de.derschimi.app.MainActivitySpecification.Should say hello world(MainActivitySpecification.groovy:15)

This is the line of code:

> ```
>    def mainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(AppActivity.class).create().get()
> ```

Is there anybody out there who is using RoboSpock? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin I consider as deprecated. At this moment I'm creating just samples how to enforce gradle java plugin understand the android one. I suggest to browse this project.
https://github.com/pjakubczyk/robospock-sample/tree/master/simple

Comment: Thanks for your help. pelotasplus did a very good job! I would upvote your answer, but I need more reputation for that ;)

Comment: as you see i'm having same problem. enjoy robospock !

Comment: If the link from Rudy does not help you, check out my project which is working now! https://github.com/DerSchimi/RoboSpockExample

Comment: If it is working now then please edit your project's main README.d and take out  "I try to use RoboSpock as a simple test framework for my Android App, but I can't get get the tests running)."